# Proof of an inequality of $L^p$ norms

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

For a general measure space, we define : $\|f\|_p= \left(\int\vert f\vert^p du\right)^{1/p}$. 
Let $0 < a < b < c < \infty$ and prove the following:
$$
\|f\|_b \leqslant \max\{\|f\|_a, \|f\|_c\}.
$$
Any help is appreciated because I dont understand the solution underneath

Comment: The idea here is that $||f||_p \leq ||f||_q$ if $1 \leq p \leq q \leq \infty$ . But the inequality reverses in $0 <p,q \leq 1$. Hope this helps.

Comment: That is to say $||f||_1$ is a point of minima.

Comment: I think here we have to use Holder inequality in some way , so can you give more details please ? 
So do I have to take cases where a>1 and when a<1 with b,c > 1 ?

Answer (score 4):

We have that

$$
\frac{1}{c}<\frac{1}{b}<\frac{1}{a}.
$$
Therefore, there exists $\alpha\in (0,1)$ such that 
$$
\frac{1}{b}=\frac{\alpha}{c}+\frac{1-\alpha}{a}.
$$
We claim that 
$$
\Vert f\Vert_b\leqslant \Vert f\Vert_c^\alpha\Vert f\Vert_a^{1-\alpha} (\ast)
$$
from where it follows that 
$$
\Vert f\Vert_b\leqslant\max\{\Vert f\Vert_a, \Vert f\Vert_c\}
$$
because 
$$
\Vert f\Vert_b\leqslant \Vert f\Vert_c^\alpha\Vert f\Vert_a^{1-\alpha}\leqslant \max\{\Vert f\Vert_a,\Vert f\Vert_c\}^{\alpha}\max\{\Vert f\Vert_a,\Vert f\Vert_c\}^{1-\alpha}=\max\{\Vert f\Vert_a,\Vert f\Vert_c\}.
$$
Now, (*) can be proved easily using Holder's Inequality as follows
$$
\int |f|^b=\int |f|^{\alpha b}|f|^{(1-\alpha)b}\leqslant \left(\int|f|^{\alpha b\frac{c}{\alpha b}}\right)^{\frac{\alpha b}{c}}\left(\int|f|^{(1-\alpha)b\frac{a}{(1-\alpha) b}}\right)^{\frac{(1-\alpha)b}{a}}=\left(\int|f|^{c}\right)^{\frac{\alpha b}{c}}\left(\int|f|^{a}\right)^{\frac{(1-\alpha)b}{a}}=\Vert f\Vert_c^{\alpha b}\Vert f\Vert_a^{(1-\alpha) b},
$$
where we have used the fact that
$$
\frac{\alpha b}{c}+\frac{(1-\alpha)b}{a}=1.
$$
Simiplifying we have the result.

Comment: Holder inequality states that for any 1<p,q<∞ , then ||f g ||1<= ||f||p ||g||q , so what is p and q here ? and the function g ?

Comment: How does the result follow from proving * ? I can't see it